# Displaying kml files with openlayers on my local drive

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am attempting to run this example: [KML layer in Openlayers doesn't work on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331997/kml-layer-in-openlayers-doesnt-work-on-localhost) locally. I did some research and found that this person had a similar issue. However he mentioned that if the files were linked locally this issue would occur. Thus I assume that if they are not linked locally I should be fine. I have tried using the javascript file directly from an example from the openlayers website: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/kml-layer.html and it will not work.

The issue being that I can see the basemap but the kml file will not show up on the map.

I have placed an example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hn5pG/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/dev/theme/default/style.csss" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/style.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1 id="title">KML Layer Example</h1>

    <div id="tags">KML</div>

    <p id="shortdesc">
        Demonstrates loading and displaying a KML file on top of a basemap.
    </p>

    <div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>

    <div id="docs">
        <p>
            A vector layer can be populated with features from a KML document
            by configuring the layer with an HTTP protocol that points to the
            KML document and is configured with a KML format for parsing features.
            The fixed strategy is used to load all features at once.
        </p>
        <p>
            View the <a href="kml-layer.js" target="_blank">kml-layer.js</a>
            source to see how this is done.
        </p>
    </div>

    <script src="http://openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/kml-layer.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Am i misinterpreting something? I only have access to firefox and internet explorer at work and need to be able to test this without hosting it if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the issue. There was a styles.kml file I was not linking to when rehosting the page. After loading this file the kml was displayed.

I still do not understand why I cannot use their js file to do the same thing however.