# Rendering local files with HTML5 in OpenLayers

Tags: html, canvas, svg, openlayers

There are some examples of HTML5's FileSystem,FileAccess features which user can add a file without sending to server side.

I'm developing a mapping application with OpenLayers,I wish to add this feature where users can either drag-drop kml file or choose kml file from a dialog,and add to map locally.

Is this behaviour possible with OpenLayers ? If so, how?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331997/kml-layer-in-openlayers-doesnt-work-on-localhost

Comment: I think that's a matter of protocol issue in Openlayers,but the example in the link has no enough details whether its support on HTML5.It's clearly answered on two years ago so that browsers that had limited FileAccess support that time.Check this link and see what I mean http://html5demos.com/file-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excerpts from this demo:

<kbd>**http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/t42cu/**</kbd>

**(fiddle updated with extension and file size check).**

Define a drop area in the html:

```
<div id="fileDrop">Drop KML file here</div>
```

Style it as you want:

```
#fileDrop {
    padding:20px;
    text-align:center;
    border:3px dashed #777;
    border-radius:12px;
    opacity:0.5;
    color:#fff;
    }
#fileDrop:hover {
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    }
```

To enable drag and drop of files you can use this code:

```
var fileDrop = document.getElementById('fileDrop');
fileDrop.addEventListener('dragover', fileDragOver, false);
fileDrop.addEventListener('drop', fileSelect, false);

// change style of the drop area when file is over
function fileDragOver(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
}

//load file on drop
function fileSelect(e) {

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    var files = e.dataTransfer.files,
        f = files[0],
        reader,

        fname = f.name.toLowerCase(),
        fsize = f.size,

        maxSize = 1024 * 1024; // 1mb

    /// Check file extension and file size
    if (fname.length < 5 || fname.substring(fname.length - 4) !=='.kml') {
        alert('Need a .kml file!');
        return;
    }

    if (fsize > maxSize) {
        alert('File is too big!');
        return;
    }

    reader = new FileReader(),

    reader.onload = function(fe) {

        var kml = fe.target.result; // the file
        gotoOpenLayer(kml);

    }
    reader.readAsText(f);
}
```

In the `gotoOpenLayer` function we convert the file to `Blob` and then to an `objectURL`:

```
function gotoOpenLayer(kml) {

    var blob = new Blob([kml], {type: 'text/plain'});
    var lnk = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    /// pass in lnk as url or kml as string to OpenLayers

    // ....
}
```

I found examples for both url loading and for passing a string.

Using the Blob URL -

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "map",
    layers: [
        new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "WMS", "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
            {layers: "basic"}
        ),
        new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({

                url: lnk, /// url goes here

                format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                    extractStyles: true, 
                    extractAttributes: true,
                    maxDepth: 2
                })
            })
        })
    ],
    center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(-112.169, 36.099),
    zoom: 11
});
```

Or by passing the loaded file as a string:

```
function getFeaturesFromKMLString (kml) {
    var format = new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
        'internalProjection': myMapObject.baseLayer.projection,
        'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
    });
    return format.read(kml);
};

// ...
myVectorLayer.addFeatures(getFeaturesFromKMLString(kml));
```

Comment: This example is excellent @Ken.I always thought that the protocol should work locally,that way we'd never use HTTP.I didn't know window can create object urls..By the way,is it possible to limit the size of file and limit the extension ?

Comment: @Myra Sure it is :) I updated the example and answer with code to check both extension and file size.